# Articles that work with covariates for mean, variance, and correlation simultaneously

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, references, parameterization, gamlss

Does anyone know of articles in which, in addition to modeling the mean parameter, are also modeled the variance and correlation parameters? I know the double generalized linear model, but they only model the variance beyond the mean! I look for an article that also models the correlation!

Note: I did not find it on google!

Comment: You mean a study published in a peer-reviewed journal? Mixed effects models also estimate variances & correlations. Whether they're reported is another issue, though.

Comment: @gung Yes, i mean a study published in a peer-reviewed journal? Or a dissertation/ thesis!

Comment: @gung I do not want to estimate a single parameter for variance and for correlation, I want to add covariates for both! That is, I want to model the mean, the variance and the correlation! In this article, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3718.pdf, the author models the mean and variance, for example!

Comment: Search this site for the tag `gamlss`

Answer (score 0):

You should search for papers using the R package `gamlss`. Some few is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030917081000062X,    https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/17/3189/2013/hess-17-3189-2013.pdf,
https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-8-59.

A [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb40&q=gamlss%20modeling%20mean%20variance%20and%20skewness%20with%20covariables&lookup=0&hl=en).